Is it mandatory for a Brahmin to teach others as per Shastra?
As per Shastra, is it necessary for a Brahmin to impart the spiritual knowledge which he has attained to others?
Does he incur any sin if he does not do so?

One popular reference is - ऋषि ऋण Rishi rina and देव ऋण deva rina
Spiritual knowledge is considered a debt from elders. It can only be repaid by teaching others, else debt remains unpaid.

How to learn from a master?
Refer Gita 4-34

Thanks. Kindly quote a verse which specifically states that a brahmana is expected to distribute knowledge and/or  the result of not doing so.
